# How to duplicate a form field in WFFM?

Tags: wffm

My WFFM form uses the same drop list of manual values 62 times. I'd much prefer to just create it once, and copy it the other 61 times, rather than building out the same drop list over and over again. Is there any way copy or duplicate an existing drop list in WFFM?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have same set of dropdown values which you want to use on multiple WFFM forms and don't want to create the same field values for each WFFM forms specifically rather want to create it once and want to re-use for all the other forms. Is that correct ?

Comment: No - I have the same set of dropdown values that I want to use over and over again on the exact same form. I know it sounds like a strange thing to want, but it makes sense in the context of this form.

Comment: Nevermind in that case as well, please refer the answer I posted below. Its always a best practice to use a droplist populating Sitecore Content Items rather creating the same droplist multiple times manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather creating a manual drop list field multiple times, I would prefer to create an item repository somewhere in the content tree (Global location is preferable) with all possible Drop List values and on the drop list field in WFFM Form map the `Set Item by` value to `Selecting Sitecore Items` rather `Manual entering names`. Thus you can reuse the same set of drop list values for any form you create.

1. Create the set of possible values in drop down using specific user defined template:

[image]

2. Create a form and define a drop list field on it:

[image]

3. Navigate to ‘List’ section:

[image]

4. Open the ‘Set Items By’ drop list:

[image]

5. Select the ‘Selecting Sitecore Items’:

[image]

6. Click on Browse and choose the repository path from the content tree:

[image]

7. It will populate all the item created under that repository. You can differentiate between ‘Value’ and ‘Text’ property here:

[image]

**Once done, all the items created under the repository will be available on your form. Which you can either use on multiple forms or multiple times on same form:**

Note: Make sure all the drop list values are published to web database.

---

**Edit 1: To duplicate a form field.**

You can navigate to the `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/<<<Your Form Path>>>` and duplicate the fields listed under that form:

> Disclaimer: I never practically tested this approach but since form
>   field is also an Sitecore Item hence I am assuming it should work.

[image]

Comment: That would get me halfway there, if I do this I won't have to create the list of values over and over which is great. However, because I need that form field many times on the exact same form, I'd still have to click "Add field," chose the drop list type, choose my CSS class from the menu, and finally navigate through the sitecore tree to choose my drop list values. And then repeat 61 times -- still a lot of manual effort! Sounds like there is no way to duplicate a WFFM form field within the same form though.

Comment: Updated my answer by adding steps to duplicate a Form Field.

Comment: Yes! Duplicating a form field like that is exactly what I needed. For others who are using SXA like I am, the path to find the form is slightly different: /sitecore/Content/<Your tennant name>/<Your site name>/Data/Forms/<Your form path>, after that the step to right click and duplicate is the same. Also, I created my possible drop list values inside that same "Forms" item as well, since my SXA site doesn't have a Global folder and the Data folder seems to be where global content is stored in SXA.

Comment: For an added bonus you could also use the Sitecore Powershell module to do your duplication - especially if your fields are going to be named "Inquiry type (1-n)" or something like that.